# Position modal centered with floating outside box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap 4 modal that I wish to display a little different. I want to display a floating box off to the left of the modal.

My question is how can I position both the modal and the floated box in the center of the page, even though the floating box is sitting outside the modal with a position absolute?

This is what it looks like currently, the floated box has a position absolute with a negative left position:

[image]

This is how I want it to look like, with the box and modal centered:

[image]

I don't know how much I have to modify the modal to do this, as I am hoping to make it responsive as well.

Would anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this? It would be much appreciated.

Thanks, guys.

```css
.affix-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="affix-box"></div>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title ml-auto" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `width: 91%;` and `left: 9%;` to `modal-content`

```css
.affix-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
.modal-content{
width: 91%;
left: 9%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="affix-box"></div>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title ml-auto" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is really close. Although the modal seems to get cut off when you minimize the browser size.

Comment: so use `@media` and set diffrent size to each screen size

Comment: Thank you, I did use media queries, and it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple replacement. 
instead of `top` and `left` i have used `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` which sets the center of the floating box on the top left corner of modal.

```css
.affix-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <!-- Button trigger modal -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="affix-box"></div>
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title ml-auto" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Joykal Infotech, that is not what my question is asking.  The modal and the floating box should be centered regardless of the floating box's negative margins or positions.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Joykal has said, you can also try changing the model size to reduce its width, you can use .modal-sm or .modal-lg class instead of .modal-xl depending on your need

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
```

Comment: Abhijit Saxena, this not what my question is asking. size doesnt matter. Regarding the modal, its trying to force both the modal and the floating box to be centered.

Comment: Krys, your 'affix-box' box division is the child of 'modal-dialog'. And if you check the css of that division you'll understand that it will force all its children to be centered. 

So if the issue is your floating box getting clipped because of the page size then you can try reducing the modal size or you need to force the floating box to appear as you want by defining the css like mentioned by Joykal.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  #myModal .close{
  display: none;
  }
  </style>

 <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
     $("#myModal").modal('show');
     $("#myModal2").modal('show');

  });

    $(".close,.close-btn").click(function(){
     $("#myModal").modal('hide');
     $("#myModal2").modal('hide');

  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
 <button type="button" class="btn">Basic</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" style="right: 50%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <!--/. Modal -->

    <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog"  style="left: 50%;">
    <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default close-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <!--/. Modal -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dipak Aher, that is not what my question is asking. Regarding your answer, Bootstrap js already makes it show and hide the modal....